# passing dictionaries to tensorflow Saver

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

In [Saver documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#saving-and-restoring-variables), it is stated that the Saver object can take either a list or dictionary as input and in case of dictionaris, the keys must be the names which will be used to save or restore variables. I have a code which looks like the following:

```
create_network()
vars_to_load_list = ...
vars_to_load_dict = {v.name:v for v in vars_to_load_list}
loader = tf.train.Saver(var_list=vars_to_load_list, max_to_keep=FLAGS.max_epoch)
path = ...
latest_ckpt = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(path, latest_filename=None)
sess = tf.Session()
ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(path)
if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
  loader.restore(sess, save_path=latest_ckpt)
```

The above code works, but if I pass in the variables dictionary instead of the varible list, i.e. change the defenition of `loader` to:

```
loader = tf.train.Saver(var_list=vars_to_load_dict, max_to_keep=FLAGS.max_epoch)
```

Then I get a `NotFoundError` and the loader complains that some Tensor names were not found in checkpoint files. But I expect both versions of the code to work the same. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the problem. Apparently, the name attribute of a variable corresponds to the value of the variable and not its tensor (if my understanding of these concepts are right). i.e. it returns  `"my_var:0"` whereas the loader requires `"my_var"`. Modifying the definition of the dictionary in the above example solves the problem:

```
vars_to_load_dict = {v.name[:-2]:v for v in vars_to_load_list}
```